# Clear CMD window from one of two functions, running at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, cmd, ascii

Recently I've learn how to write ASCII animation in Python. I would like to use it with other part of the program that is running at the same time. The problem is, animation use clear() function:

```
def clear():
os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
```

The problem about clear() is, that it delete everything from the screen, while I want just to delete inside of one function, and keep other function on the screen. How would you do that?

https://onlinegdb.com/ryjg3H1U7

PS.Animation that I made in ASCI^^
https://onlinegdb.com/Bk0d2HyLX

Comment: Use a library like [**`asciimatics`**](https://pypi.org/project/asciimatics/)

Comment: maybe remove clear and use print_at instead of print?

Comment: @PeterWood I'm trying to get my head around asciimatics, as you suggested, but I'm stucked on effects composition in the code. Would you be able to help me out with it maybe?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010828/ascii-asciimatics-how-to-implement-effects-screens-into-the-code

Comment: I know nothing about it. stack overflow is for posting clear questions and getting clear answers, not for asking a particular person for help. See [ask] and the [help/on-topic]